# roscd can't find packages

Tags: ros, roslaunch, roscd, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ,

i'm using ros indigo and suddenly after reboot my pc i can't run some package , for example when i try to type :

"roscd turtle "  and use the tab touch keyboard it gives only these packages

```
 turtle_actionlib/        turtlebot_description/   turtle_tf/
turtlebot_capabilities/  turtlesim/               turtle_tf2/
```

so why it can't  detect turtlbot_teleop and other packages ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300454/roscd-can%27t-find-packages/) by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-08-20**:
i had a problem with ubuntu so i dit réinstall it and everything worls fine

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2018-08-20**:
Have you tried rospack find turtlebot_teleop ? If rospack can't find it, then it must've been deleted if you did a apt-get autoremove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried sourcing the setup file again? This must be done for every fresh console.
Do
cd ~/path/to/your/catkin_workspace
source devel/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [totalnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/37015/totalnewbie/) with karma: 18 on 2018-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0